# Elements of horizontal navbar do not top align

Tags: html, css, navbar

I would like to align the elements of my navbar vertically on large screens and horizontally on small screens. This works well, except on small screens one element is not top-aligned but slightly moved downwards (see image). **How do I get the elements of the horizontal navbar top-aligned?** I would like the "Publications" element to be top-aligned with the "Teaching" and "Home" elements.

Adding `align: top` to different CSS environments had no effect.

Thank you for your help.

[image: wrongly aligned horizontal navbar]

```css
.nav {
 padding-left:10px; 
}

.nav ul {
  all: unset;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 5px;
}

.nav ul li {
 all: unset;
 padding: 2px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.nav ul li a {
  all: unset;
  display: block;
  color: #AFBDD5;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

.nav ul li a:hover, .nav ul li a:focus, a:hover, a:visited, details summary:hover {
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #AFBDD5;
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    
    .nav {
      float: left;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .nav ul li a {
      float: left;
      display: inline;
      color: #AFBDD5;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #010B14;
      border: 1px solid #FBFEF9;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .nav ul li a:hover, .nav ul li a:focus, a:hover, a:visited, details summary:hover {
      border-bottom: none;
    }

}
```

```html
        <div class="nav">
          <ul>
          
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          
          <li><a href="teaching.html">Teaching</a></li>
          
          <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
          
          <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
          
          <li><a href="cv.html">CV</a></li>
          
          <li><a href="student-work.html">Borrowed Plumes</a></li>
          
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work. Post compiled code.

Comment: I have added runable code.

Comment: Your code is still incomplete. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/fx2nLm35/. BTW `align: top` is not valid css. Maybe you're looking for `vertical-align: top`. None of those are actually found in your code.

Comment: Adding any of those does not make any difference which is why they are not included in the code. Following your link reproduces exactly my problem. What is still missing from the code in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Check this one out. Dont use float use flex instead.

```css
 .nav {
        padding-left: 10px;
      }

      .nav ul {
        all: unset;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 0 10px 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .nav ul li {
        all: unset;
        padding: 2px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .nav ul li a {
        all: unset;
        display: block;
        color: #afbdd5;
        font-family: Sans-Serif;
      }

      .nav ul li a:hover,
      .nav ul li a:focus,
      a:hover,
      a:visited,
      details summary:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #afbdd5;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .nav {
          margin-top: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .nav ul li a {
          color: #afbdd5;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px;
          background-color: #010b14;
          border: 1px solid #fbfef9;
          margin-right: 5px;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .nav ul {
          flex-direction: row;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .nav ul li a:hover,
        .nav ul li a:focus,
        a:hover,
        a:visited,
        details summary:hover {
          border-bottom: none;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="teaching.html">Teaching</a></li>

        <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>

        <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>

        <li><a href="cv.html">CV</a></li>

        <li><a href="student-work.html">Borrowed Plumes</a></li>

        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: The elements are now top-aligned but now they are not left-aligned anymore. How would I get them top-aligned and left-aligned?

Comment: I accepted this answer because it pointed me in the right direction. Thank you. I replaced `flex-wrap: wrap;` with `flex-wrap: nowrap;` and added `overflow: scroll;`. Now I have a top-aligned row of elements that is horizontally scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `display: flex` and `align-items`, `justify-content` properties.

Follow these links for more information.

- [justify-content property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp)
- [align-items property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).